# Determine a connection loss/deriving an isConnectionLost state while using RTK Query

Tags: redux-toolkit, rtk-query

There is a notistack example displaying a snack bar when a connection loss occures: https://notistack.com/examples#dismiss-programmatically

My interest is in how to actually determine this while using RTK Query to access endpoints solely on servers under my control.
I guess determining a timeout is enough. Is an error already there in **error** despite not being an http error or can I assume a timeout when both **isSuccess** and **isError** are false?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next version (1.9) of RTK Query will allow you to use a `timeout` option with `fetchBaseQuery` and add a `{code: 'TIMEOUT_ERROR'}` error.

If you look at [the 1.9 integration PR](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/pull/2401) you can already install that from the CodeSandbox CI build.

Comment: Is it now implemented?

Comment: @Normal Yes: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/fetchBaseQuery#timeout